# Change text style / size of selected value in NumberPicker

Tags: android

I've got two problems to custom my numberpicker on my application. After lot of research I didn't found anything that help me.

First is that I want increase the selected text. I already have a class that extends number picker to customize the general text size, font and divider visibility, but I'm not able to increase only the selected value.

Second problems, I want to put some unicode on my text, so I'm trying to use a spannableString[] instead of String[] for the formattter, but nothing seems to work. I would use Spannable to be able to change the police font of a little part of my text (With some Regex)

Is there a way to do this ?

What I've done actually :

```
public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker{

private Context context;

public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void addView(View child) {
    super.addView(child);
    updateView(child);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    updateView(child);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, params);
    updateView(child);
}

private void updateView(View view) {
    if(view instanceof EditText){

        //Text size
        ((EditText) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);

        //Text font
        Typeface robotoFont = FontCache.get("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf", getContext());
        ((EditText) view).setTypeface(robotoFont);
    }

    //Non visible selectors
    java.lang.reflect.Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field pf : pickerFields) {
        if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
            pf.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(
                        getContext(), R.color.colorTransparent
                ));
                pf.set(this, colorDrawable);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

THe formatter :

```
 npTemp.setMinValue(0);
    npTemp.setMaxValue(values.length - 1);
    NumberPicker.Formatter formatter = new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(int value) {
            return values[value];
        }
    };
    npTemp.setFormatter(formatter);
```

What I've tried to get the selected value EditText on my custom Number picker

```
java.lang.reflect.Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field pf : pickerFields) {
        if (pf.getName().equals("mInputType")) {
            pf.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                ((EditText)pf).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

And to have SpannableString, I've done lot of things but the formatter only want String.

Thanks for helping

Comment: did get the solution? Because I'm also looking for same requirement

Comment: No I didn't. I just change the NumberPicker design to workaround the problem.

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/Carbs0126/NumberPickerView Using this library, You can increase size of selected number. Hope this helps for you

Comment: but no edittext selection

Comment: no native provision either than using the library?